# Unable to modify form in Access when linked to ArcGIS using database connection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access

I created a split Access 2010 database with a back-end for just tables and the front end with queries and forms.  The front-end is linked using an OLE DB connection to ArcGIS, which works fine.  When the database connection is connected I am unable to modify my forms but I can update and create queries.

Could this be an issue with having the forms bound to my table query? or is it because I am using a table query for the form?  I don't know how to update my table records from the form without it being bound to the table. I am also using the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider.

This is a multiple user database and other users maybe linking this to ArcGIS and might also need to make modifications.

Comment: I hate to be one of those people, but Access presents many challenges when used as a multi-user database.  This answer might help with general guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684630/2258

Comment: I ran into the issue awhile back.  The problem is once ArcMap connects to an Access database, Access creates one of those lock files, which is what is preventing you from modifying the forms.  To make the situation even more annoying, the only way to release the lock is to completely close out ArcMap.  In my case, the workaround I found was to connect to the database and run queries through ArcObjects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023861/how-to-connect-access-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have never used ArcObjects, where do I add the code to connect to the database? And I am only able to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a better way of doing this but I have found a solution.  My solution was to copy the database with the forms and queries, and link the copy to ArcGIS.  Because it is still linked with the main tables I only have to use the original database to add data via forms without opening the linked database.  If other users need to use the database they can make a copy and modify it now without an exclusive lock.